# Parse Cloud architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, cloud

Are there any links / documentations available on cloud architecture of Parse?

I know it's built on top of AWS, but I am looking for something more detailed.

It's for a expository paper.

thanks

Comment: Amazing how people would down vote, without even giving a reason.

Comment: The reason your question probably got down voted is because it does not seem well researched. [Please reference this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are.

[Here is the Parse case study](http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/parse/).
 
[Here is their re:Invent presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paTjmG3b22I).